# How to display the string “overbought” one time only on top of bar

Tags: pine-script

I want to display “overbought” one time when rsi is >90. Preferably the last candle that is > 90. That mean the word overbought is not display on the previous recent candle. Every time a new candle update, the previous word overbought get deleted. However the condition reset when the future value is greater than 90. The word overbought only display once on different timeframe; however only one per trigger

Comment: If you show some code with the problem it might help.